# Material-UI - how to get CSS class content generated by JSS? Not just the static CSS, But dynamic classes as well

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss, css-in-js

I am using Material UI in my react project and I know it's using JSS behind the scenes. As per Material UI documentation in the server rendering apps, we can get the CSS string using the below code,

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#serverstylesheets

I am trying to use the same in my browser app [only client-side no server rendering]. I have a requirement where I need to get the whole CSS generated by Material UI as a string for converting it as a PDF using Puppeteer. I am struggling to get the CSS out of MUI. I am able to fetch all the CSS classes added when the page renders, however, If we dynamically change a Material UI style, it gets a random name by JSS, eg: `.MuiTableCell-root-54` I have no idea where this class is [Not on the DOM as  tag. Not for the dynamic class names after render]. Is there any way I can get the content of such a dynamic class using JSS API or Material UI API?

Comment: check https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#react-class-name-hydration-mismatch

Comment: "My App doesn't render correctly on the server" is not my problem. I don't have Server Side Rendering. I need MUI class content on the client-side like they do in server rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally !!! I got what I wanted without using anything from JSS or Material UI. I used the below code to get all the CSS applied on an HTML page,

```
function extractCSS(node) {
  const allCSS = [...document.styleSheets]
    .map((styleSheet) => {
      try {
        return [...styleSheet.cssRules].map((rule) => rule.cssText).join("");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(
          "Access to stylesheet %s is denied. Ignoring...",
          styleSheet.href
        );
      }
    })
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join("");

  return allCSS;
}

export { extractCSS };
```

node is the HTML element I am passing. I haven't optimized the code to get only those CSS under the node. But this works. I will have some CSS that's not needed though !! Thanks to MDN. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList